# jquery swap ul childs between two ul's

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following html with two lists, and I want to press a button and swap the ul's, li´s elements between the two

```
<ul class="list-group" id="lines">
<li class="list-group-item> 1 <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
<li class="list-group-item> 2 <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
</ul>

<ul class="list-group" id="columns">
<li class="list-group-item> 3 <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
<li class="list-group-item> 4 <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
</ul>
```

I have tried to accomplish this with the following jquery code

```
$("#swaplists").click(function () {

 var $temp1 = $("#lines").children.clone;
 var $temp2 = $("#columns").children.clone;
 clearLinesAndColumns();
 $temp2.appendTo("#lines");
 $temp1.appendTo("#columns");

});
```

the expected result would be

```
<ul class="list-group" id="lines">
<li class="list-group-item> 3 <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
<li class="list-group-item> 4 <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
</ul>

<ul class="list-group" id="columns">
<li class="list-group-item> 1 <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
<li class="list-group-item> 2 <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>   
</ul>
```

But I get the error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendTo' of undefined

How can I achieve this functionality with jquery and why is `children.clone` undefined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of cloning and appending, you can simply get the `html()` and insert in other:

```js
$("#swaplists").click(function() {
  var linesHtml = $("#lines").html();
  var columnsHtml = $("#columns").html();
  $("#lines").html(columnsHtml);
  $("#columns").html(linesHtml);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list-group" id="lines">
  <li class="list-group-item"> 1 <i class=" fa fa-times " aria-hidden="true "></i></li>
  <li class="list-group-item"> 2 <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
</ul>

<ul class="list-group" id="columns">
  <li class="list-group-item"> 3 <i class=" fa fa-times " aria-hidden="true "></i></li>
  <li class="list-group-item"> 4 <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
</ul>

<button id="swaplists">Swap</button>
```

Comment: I prefer this solution. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#swaplists").click(function () {

 var $temp1 = $("#lines").children().clone();
 var $temp2 = $("#columns").children().clone();
 clearLinesAndColumns();
 $temp2.appendTo("#lines");
 $temp1.appendTo("#columns");

});
```

You forgot to put '()' after calling 'children' and 'clone'...those are methods.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample code:

```js
$("#swaplists").click(function() {

  var $temp1 = $("#lines li");
  var $temp2 = $("#columns li");

  $temp2.appendTo("#lines");
  $temp1.appendTo("#columns");

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list-group" id="lines">
  <li class="list-group-item"> 1 <i class="fa fa-times " aria-hidden="true "></i></li>
  <li class="list-group-item"> 2 <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
</ul>

<ul class="list-group" id="columns">
  <li class="list-group-item"> 3 <i class=" fa fa-times " aria-hidden="true "></i></li>
  <li class="list-group-item"> 4 <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
</ul>

<button id="swaplists">SWAP LISTS</button>
```